# Is the motion of proton in EM described by the Schroedinger equation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, protons

Does the usual Schroedinger equation describing the non-relativistic motion of electron in electromagnetic field also describes non-relativistic motion of proton? (Of course the values of charge and mass of electron should be replaced by those of proton).

Comment: Is there a reason it shouldn't?

Comment: @GiorgioP: Proton is different from electron by its structure: e.g. it is not an elementary particle.  In any case I am wondering if there is an experimental confirmation of the validity of the equation.

Comment: @MKO At a non-relativistic level, the proton *is* a fundamental particle. Its compositeness features only come into play at very high energies. Even in relativistic QM we can talk about the proton as a whole, without knowing anything of it's structure, what come into play at this point are its physical size, magnetic properties etc. which are summarized into its [form factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_factor_(quantum_field_theory))

Comment: @DavideMorgante In relativistic quantum chemistry the finite size effect of the proton is often taken into account.

Comment: @my2cts Yes, in fact the finite size of the proton is accounted for in quantum field theory. But, in certain approximations, even that can be excluded. My comment was just to make it clear that this properties only come up when talking about relativistic theories. I'm sure that even in some non-relativistic limit, such properties can be taken into account, but I imagine it would be some specific cases.

Comment: The Schrödinger is in no way restricted to elementary particles.

Comment: In fact, it is the Dirac equation that can only describe electrons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only protons, but also nuclei *can be described* by the Schrödinger equation, and in fact one routinely does so.

**When can we do so?**
Obviously in the non-relativistic limit, i.e., at low energies. One aspect of such a low energy description is that the internal structure of the proton/nucleus is inaccessible, i.e., we can neglect all the interactions except the electromagnetic ones. This imposes interesting limitations on the description of neutrons and other charged particles - although they still can couple to the electromagnetic field via their spin.

**When do we actually do so?**
When solving Schrödinger equations for atoms one starts with a system of particles including the electrons and the nucleus and then transforms to its center of mass. Since the nucleus is much heavier than electrons (even in a hydrogen atom), one often talks about electrons moving in a central field with a fixed origin. However, many books on quantum mechanics do present this derivation.

Another case when we do so is in applying the Born-Oppenheimer approximation for solids, separating the movement of heavy nuclei and the light electrons. Note that we then go on studying the quantum behavior of these nuclei, e.g., when quantizing the lattice vibrations (phonons), although the explicit Schrödinger equation is rarely written in this context.